# Splitting Lists

Tags: list, split, tcl

How do I split the below List

```
\{ X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/1 island ethernet10/1\} \{ X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/2 island ethernet10/3\} \{ X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/3 island ethernet10/5\}
```

like below :

```
Element 1  - X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/1 island ethernet10/1
Element 2 X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/2 island ethernet10/3
Element 3 X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/3 island ethernet10/5
```

Comment: I wonder if your "list elements" do really contain those literal `\{` and `\}`? Another thing to note is that if it's really *a list,* there's nothing to split -- just use `lindex` on it to extract a required element. If, instead, this is a string, then the question becomes more complicated. I would like you to elaborate on your problem statement as I have a feeling you don't have understanding of how lists and their *string representations* are related in Tcl.

Comment: A piece of code which *produces* the list you want to split would be enough to gain more understanding of your problem.

Comment: @perreal's answer solved my problem . \{ and \} may be used to ignore the special characters as well which looks to be the case here . Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set a "\{ X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/1 island ethernet10/1\} \{ X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/2 island ethernet10/3\} \{ X.1.Agg-252 ethernet4/3 island ethernet10/5\}"
set y [split $a \{\}]
foreach w $y {puts $w}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var splits = yourString.Replace("{", string.Empty).Split('}');
```

Comment: Hi @Herman - Thanks , I was looking for something in Tcl though